# Отображение поля БД в виде группы Checkbox'ов

Tags: python, django

Добрый день. В проекте две модели: Документ (номер, имя, дата, тип (внешний ключ), комментарий) и Типы документов (идентификатор, тип). 
На страничке на сайте выводится список всех документов и форма поиска: текстовое поле, где поиск идёт по номеру, имени или комментарию. Моё задание - добавить в форму поиска группу Checkbox'ов - перечень типов документов, чтобы можно было сортировать результаты поиска.

models.py.

```
class DocumentType(models.Model):
globalid = models.CharField(max_length=38, unique=True, editable=False, default=braced_uuid,
    verbose_name='GlobalID')
type = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False, db_index=True,
    verbose_name='тип документа')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.type

class Meta:
    db_table = u'document_type'
    verbose_name = 'тип документа'
    verbose_name_plural = 'типы документов'

class Document(models.Model):
    doc_no = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, db_index=True,
        verbose_name='номер документа')
    doc_date = models.DateField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True,
        verbose_name='дата документа')
    doc_type = models.ForeignKey(DocumentType, to_field='globalid', default = 'Тип не выбран',
        verbose_name='тип документа')
    doc_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, db_index=True,
        verbose_name='название документа')
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, db_index=True,
        verbose_name='примечание')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.doc_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'document'
        verbose_name = 'документ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'документы'
```

forms.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django import forms

from archive.models import Document, DocumentType

type_list = [x.type for x in DocumentType.objects.all()]

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search_string = forms.CharField(required=False,
        label="Поиск")
    top_level = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True,
        label="Только документы верхнего уровня")
    doc_types = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=type_list, required=False, initial=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def list(request):
# Search conditions can be obtained from the search form (POST data)
# or from GET parameter.
if request.method == 'POST':
    search_form = SearchForm(request.POST)
    if search_form.is_valid():
        search = search_form.cleaned_data['search_string']
        top_level = search_form.cleaned_data['top_level']
        doc_types = search_form.cleaned_data['doc_types']
else:
    search = request.GET.get('search', '')
    top_level = request.GET.get('top_level', 'true').lower() != 'false'
    doc_types = request.GET.get('doc_types', 'true').lower() != 'false'
    search_form = SearchForm(
        {'search_string': search, 'top_level': top_level, 'doc_types': doc_types})

# We must have at least one match for each search word.
# Some fields require exact match, some have to contain the word.
if search:
    search_words = search.split()
    doc_list = Document.objects
    for word in search_words:
        doc_list = doc_list.filter(
            Q(doc_name__icontains=word) | Q(doc_tags__icontains=word) |
            Q(doc_no__icontains=word) | Q(archive_no__icontains=word) |
            Q(doc_group__icontains=word) | Q(address__icontains=word) |
            Q(comments__icontains=word)
        )
    doc_list = doc_list.order_by('doc_name')
else:
    doc_list = Document.objects.order_by('doc_name')
if top_level:
    doc_list = doc_list.filter(Q(parent__isnull=True) | Q(parent=''))
context = {
    'search_form': search_form, # Django form for document searching
    'search': search, # Space separated search keywords
    'top_level': top_level, # Search among top-level documents only
    'doc_types': doc_types, # Search only checked types of all documents
    'documents': documents, # Paginator page
    }
return render(request, 'archive/list.html', context)
```

list.html

```
{% block actions %}

{% if perms.document.add %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'archive-new' %}">Добавить документ</a></li>
{% endif %}

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        {{ search_form.as_ul }}
        <li><input type="submit" value="Найти" class="search"></li><br />
    </fieldset>
    <br />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

При загрузке страницы выходит ошибка в строке "{{ search_form.as_ul }}" из list.html - too many values to unpack
Что именно не нравится дебаггеру?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблема была не в коде, код работает.
Если подробнее, то по моему недосмотру склонировался views.py в соседнюю директорию, и я работала не с тем views.py. Спасибо всем интересовавшимся!

После редактирования стиля вывода list.html приобрёл следующий вид:

```
{% block actions %}

{% if perms.document.add %}
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'archive-new' %}">Добавить документ</a>
</li>
<br />
{% endif %}

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<br />
{{ search_form.search_string.label }}
{{ search_form.search_string }}
{{ search_form.top_level.label }}
{{ search_form.top_level }}
<br />
<fieldset>
    <br />
    {{ search_form.doc_types.label }}
    <br />
    {{ search_form.doc_types }}
    <br />
    <li><input type="submit" value="Найти" class="search"></li>
</fieldset> 
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Теперь строки выводятся по очереди, а Checkbox-ы одной строкой. Пока не получилось выводить каждый Checkbox на новой строке.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите полное решение проблемы и поставьте себе галочку, так работает StackOverflow, возможно ваш опыт пригодится остальным

Comment: я смогу принять ответ через 22 часа - так пишут при нажатии на галочку.